# Use Array From Function 1 in Function 2

Tags: php, arrays, function, boolean

I have a (simplified) function that uses `in_array()` to check if a value is in an array:

```
function is($input) {
    $class = array('msie','ie','ie9');
    $is = FALSE;
    if (in_array($input, $class)) {$is = TRUE;}
    return $is;
}

if (is('msie')) 
    echo 'Friends don\'t let friends use IE.';
```

I want to break this into two separate functions, where the **first** defines the array:

```
   function myarray() {
        $class = array('msie','ie','ie9');
    }
```

and the **second** runs the check—either like this:

```
function is($input) {
    myarray();
    $is = FALSE;
    if (in_array($input, $class)) {$is = TRUE;}
    return $is;
}
```

Or this:

```
function is($input) {
    global $class;
    $is = FALSE;
    if (in_array($input, $class)) {$is = TRUE;}
    return $is;
}
```

But both of the above cause this error:

```
Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/vanetten/temp.ryanve.com/PHP/airve.php on line 73
```

What is the proper way use an array from one function in another? Can an array be a global variable? How do I make this work? Is it more efficient to use a global variable or to call the first function within the second function. Any help is definitely appreciated.

Comment: `myarray()` is a one line function, why segregate it and not just keep it inline?

Comment: I just simplified myarray() here. The actual function definition is much longer (it's  http://dev.airve.com/code/html_class/html_class.201106130230.php without the output string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return the array from the first function:

```
function myarray() {
    return array('msie','ie','ie9');
}

function is($input) {
    $array = myarray();
    return in_array($input, $array);
    // or even just
    // return in_array($input, myarray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is($input) {
  $class = myarray();
  $is = false;
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way (which also negates the use of global variables, which is a bad practice since using `$class` somewhere else down the line may result in unexpected behavior) is something like

```
function myarray() {
    return array('msie','ie','ie9');
}

function is($input) {
    $array = myarray();
    $is = FALSE;
    if (in_array($input, $array)) {$is = TRUE;}
    return $is;
}

if (is('msie')) 
    echo 'Friends don\'t let friends use IE.';
```

In this example, we just make `myarray()` return the needed array. In `is()`, add the line `$array = myarray()`, which will save the array from `myarray()`, so it is useable from `is()` as the alias `$array`. Then simply change `$class` to `$array`, and it should work fine.

Comment: Yea figured if I were going to use a global variable, then I would have to rename it more uniquely. From a performance standpoint, would using a global better than calling the function with the function, or does it not make a difference? I'd like to be able to use is() multiple times on a page (similar in usage to WordPress' conditional tags).

Comment: @ryanve From looking at your code it looks like you might have a slight performance overhead from calling it multiple times, mainly due to the numerous `preg` functions. You could always assign a variable, such as `$_class` in the global scope (IE, top of the page) that is set to `myarray()` and then pass that value into `is()` whenever you need it via `is($_class)`. This will reduce the overhead of calling `myarray()` multiple times, but will also help alleviate the problems generally arsing from using pure global variables.

Comment: I just tested it both ways, running the function 100 times. It's milliseconds, but right there's definitely a difference between the two methods. Look here: [link]http://dev.airve.com/demo/speed_tests/ I'm planning on releasing / open sourcing all the airve_ functions (as a mini framework of sorts). Thanks for the help!